# Mechanics question about energy

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

A body of 10 kg weight drops from a height  of 60 cm upon a spring whose modulus is 60 kg/cm . What will be the speed of the block when the spring is deformed 2 cm?

Comment: Why the QM tag? And what're your own thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Use energy conservation principle 
 $$mgh=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+\frac{1}{2}kx^2  $$
$m,h,k \ and\ x $ are given, $g$ you know, get $v$.